# How to get files from a remote Branch to your local Branch [Github]

Tags: git, github, github-app

After i commited certain files/changes to a remote branch through the Github Desktop App, i would like to get those changes to the local branch. I do work with SAP Web IDE.

**What i tried:**

```
fetch
```

**Issue:** Didn't really work out

**Question:** How to get the data of the remote Branch to a local Branch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git fetch` to update your local references to the remote branch. In other words: `git fetch` checks for updates on the remote repository, but does not yet merge any updates to your local repository. After fetching, use `git merge` or `git rebase` to integrate the remote changes into your local repo.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to retrieve data from `remote` branch to your `local` branch.

1. The simplest one is `pull`. Just run the following command.

   ```sh
   $ git pull
   ```
2. Another way to do it is to `merge`. But before you have to `fetch`.

   ```sh
   $ git fetch
   $ git merge
   ```
3. You can also use `rebase`. It also requires `fetch`.

   ```sh
   $ git fetch
   $ git rebase
   ```
4. Another interesting way is to `fetch` your remote branch and `reset` your local branch to the `remote` branch. Lets just say, your local branch is `sample`. Then just run the followings.

   ```sh
   $ git fetch
   $ git reset --hard origin/sample
   ```